# MS Access Query Compare Value from Previous row

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

Is there a way to compare From and to, to see if FROM is lesser that the previous TO value?

like this

| FROM | TO | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | OK |
| 0.5 | 2 | ERROR |
| 2 | 3 | OK |
| 3.1 | 4 | OK |
| 3.25 | 4.9 | ERROR |
| 4.11 | 5 | OK |

This is in Query. And I do not know how to do the comparing to a previous record

```
SELECT T_Alteration.[HOLE ID], T_Alteration.FROM, T_Alteration.TO, T_Alteration.Length, T_Alteration.[Alt Code], T_Alteration.Remarks, IIf(IsNull([Alteration].[HoleID]),"","SKIPPED -Already in Record!") AS Status
FROM T_Alteration LEFT JOIN Alteration ON (T_Alteration.TO = Alteration.GEOLTO) AND (T_Alteration.FROM = Alteration.GEOLFROM) AND (T_Alteration.[HOLE ID] = Alteration.HoleID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with this:

```sql
SELECT 
    T_Alteration.[HOLE ID], 
    T_Alteration.FROM, 
    T_Alteration.TO, 
    IIf(
        Nz([FROM]<
            (Select Top 1 T.TO 
            From T_Alteration As T 
            Where T.FROM < T_Alteration.FROM 
            Order By T.FROM Desc),
        False),
        "ERROR",
        "OK") AS Result
FROM 
    T_Alteration;
```

Output:

[image]

You may have the question how it works, so I asked **Copilot** to explain that.

Withing five seconds she replied:

> This query is selecting data from a table named `T_Alteration`. Here's
> a breakdown of what each part does:
>
> 1. `SELECT T_Alteration.[HOLE ID], T_Alteration.FROM, T_Alteration.TO`: This part of the query is selecting three columns
>    from the `T_Alteration` table: `HOLE ID`, `FROM`, and `TO`.
> 2. `IIf(Nz([FROM]<(Select Top 1 T.TO From T_Alteration As T Where T.FROM < T_Alteration.FROM Order By T.FROM Desc), False), "ERROR", "OK") AS Result`: This part of the query is a bit more complex. It's
>    creating a new column in the result set named `Result`. The value of
>    `Result` is determined by the `IIf` function, which is an if-then-else
>    construct.
>
>    - The `IIf` function takes three arguments: a condition, the value to return if the condition is true, and the value to return if the
>      condition is false. In this case, the condition is `Nz([FROM]<(Select Top 1 T.TO From T_Alteration As T Where T.FROM < T_Alteration.FROM Order By T.FROM Desc), False)`.
>    - `Nz` is a function that returns the first argument if it is not null; otherwise, it returns the second argument. Here, it's checking
>      whether the `FROM` value of the current row is less than the `TO`
>      value of the row from `T_Alteration` where `FROM` is less than the
>      `FROM` of the current row and has the highest such `FROM` value. If
>      the `FROM` value of the current row is null or if there's no such row
>      in `T_Alteration`, `Nz` returns `False`.
>    - If the condition is true (i.e., if `FROM` is less than the `TO` value of the row with the highest `FROM` value less than the current
>      row's `FROM` value), `IIf` returns `"ERROR"`. Otherwise, it returns
>      `"OK"`.
> 3. `FROM T_Alteration`: This part of the query specifies the table that the data is being selected from, which is `T_Alteration`.
>
> So, in summary, this query is selecting the `HOLE ID`, `FROM`, and
> `TO` values from each row in `T_Alteration`, along with a `Result`
> value that is `"OK"` if `FROM` is not less than the `TO` value of the
> row with the highest `FROM` value less than the current row's `FROM`
> value, and `"ERROR"` otherwise. If the `FROM` value of the current row
> is null or if there's no such row in `T_Alteration`, the `Result`
> value is also `"OK"`.

A good example, I think, of the capability of **Copilot**.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I love how you guys explained it to me. this is very useful. i need to bookmark this :)